# fitting a background for different screen

Tags: html, css

I created a background for my website using CSS code it successfully worked but the problem is  once I run it on different screen whether it was big or small I don't get similar consequences. When I run it on `13 inch screen` the browser **zooms** in and the form what I get is probably not the same as in `18 inch` well it obviously wouldn't have the exactly form but more or less I need it to be shown look-like. any suggestions? thnx in advance

```
body {
background-image: url(../images/background.jpg);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
    }
```

An addition problem I have now is that the background isn't full-screen. its resolution is 1920x1080, though I can see the picture on the whole web browser page but still I couldn't see other details of the photo.

Comment: You might have to dynamically set the font size depending on the available screen dimensions. You can do that using javascript. However this rarely is a good idea. HTML markup is meant to describe a page, it is _not_ a means to do absolute layouting tasks. The web is not good for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need

```
background-size: cover;
```

There are some browser inconsistencies, which might mean it is better to use a jquery plugin.

Have a look at http://srobbin.com/jquery-plugins/backstretch/ it allows you to use a background image which resizes depending on the size of the screen. It also deals with IE. Nuff said.

Also look at http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/

I'm not 100% on what you are trying to achieve but the above links are worth a look.

This is the css3 way

```
html { 
    background: url(../images/background.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: What browser are you using?